# git-bash $PATH cannot parse windows directory with space

Tags: windows, git, path, git-shell

I would like to use git-bash come with github client on a windows 7 (32bit) machine. Somehow, the git-bash has already learned the `$PATH` variables from windows system `PATH`. However, I found the `$PATH` in git-bash did not parse the win system PATH with space correctly.

for example the `$PATH` outputs:

> "..../c/Program: No such file or directory"

Is there anyway to fix it? where is the git-bash script to construct the `$PATH` for git shell?
Thanks

Answer (score 46):

Why not using absolute `path` instead of relative `path` and if a folder of file name contains a space just use `""` (quotes).

Ex. `cd C:/Users/"My Folder"`

Comment: This didn't work for me. But `/c/Users/My\ Folder/` did.

Answer (score 27):

Put a backslash ("`\`") before the space.

ex. `cd My\ Documents`

Answer (score 2):

I am having similar problem.

After some struggle, i put this on the first line in my `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile`:

> export HOME=`cygpath -u "\`cygpath -d "$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"\`"`

and type command `echo $HOME` in bash will come out `/c/Users/NAMEXX~1`, no more space parsing problem for my `$HOME` or `~/` !

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was close to that of Seagal82.
I added the following line at the start of `[PATH_TO_GITBASH_INSTALL]\etc\profile`:

```
export HOME="/c/Users/Username\ with\ spaces/"
```

Then I started a new git bash window and all the paths in `$PATH` using `$HOME` got replaced with the anti-slashed space and work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically to confirm what is working: 
For environment variables use export keyword:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/c/Program Files/Java/jdkxxxxx"
```

same for PATH variable etc.

You can put it in your ~/.bashrc . Then, use variables instead of direct string with spaces

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash declare command -

```
$ declare -x PATH="/path with spaces":$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape non-word-characters with a backslash "\":

For Example:

```
$ cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t do that, you can try this instead pass the complete path in the `""`(quotes).
Example`$ cd "C:\Users\folder\OneDrive - folder\file"`

Answer (score 0):

`git-bash` runs in a `Linux` environment. As, linux doesn't recognize `\ backslash` in its directory path, you need to use `/ forwardslash`. Use `""` if you directory path contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to appreciate, specifically if in a Windows OS `Git Bash` shell "setting", the possibility to use "short names" ie the foldername info you get when you run `dir /X` in a directory and then use that eg for `Program Files` this would be `PROGRA~1` (which contains no spaces anymore). Then using that shortname in paths or similar definitions within the `.bashrc` (or similar) files.
As an additional info [here] `Program Files (x86)` shortname would be `PROGRA~2`
I recently discovered this to be the most stable solution for exporting a variable in `Git Bash`'s `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to set a convenience environment variable pointing inside my OneDrive for Business folder, which was something like
/c/Users/username/OneDrive - Business Name/somefolder

So in /c/Users/username/.profile I have a line like

```
export FOLDER='/c/Users/username/OneDrive - Business Name/somefolder'
```

Note the single quotes. When I want to use that environment variable I still have to double quote it for it to work, e.g:

```
$ cd "$FOLDER"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after switching to Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta which places ssh.exe at `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` instead of the old location at `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`,

so Git needed to use the new location, and after trying every suggestion here, what finally worked for me was `\"C:/Program Files/OpenSSH/ssh.exe\"`.

```
PS> git config --global core.sshCommand
"C:/Program Files/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```