# Extend $PATH variable in git bash under Windows

Tags: path, mingw, git-bash

I'm trying to extend my $PATH variable in git bash (MinGW shell) by adding the following to the file ~/.bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH':/c/Program Files/maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin'
```

After I did this and restarted the bash it seems like that the $PATH variable was extended like expected:

```
$ echo $PATH
MANY_OTHER_PATHS:/c/Program Files/maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin
```

But I still cannot execute the programms in the given directory:

```
$ mvn
bash: mvn: command not found
```

What went wrong here? How do I extend the PATH variable correctly?

Comment: Suspect you need to escape the space in Program Files. Try Program\ Files.

Comment: Thats also not working. I've already tried that before

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here are two ideas.

You can have your path with double quote mark.

> export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"

[image]

Or, You can also make symbolic link for the directory.

> ln -s "/C/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin" ./mvnbin
>   export  PATH=$PATH:/your-path/mvnbin

[image]

It works for me in mingw32 environment.

Comment: You could also create an alias (basically equivalent to symlink).

Comment: Okey,  it can be an option thanks but also you can answer him

Comment: When I run the first command (to add a directory to `PATH`) I get an unhelpful error "`bash: /c/my/path: Is a directory`" (of course it's a directory!) even though my syntax is the same as yours (just a different folder path). Any idea?

Comment: Making it an alias and then adding that to the path worked for me. Just add the individual binaries to the path with aliases.

Answer (score 18):

I needed to add something to my Git Bash path permanently each time I open it. It was Meld.exe path which can be added with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files (x86)/Meld/lib"
```

In order to execute this command each bash session, you need a `~/.bashrc` file. Check if it already exists or create it using `notepad ~/.bashrc` or `touch ~/.bashrc`.

You can check where it is with:

```
echo ~
```

Open it and add the command that adds the PATH (first command in this response).

I hope you found this useful.

Answer (score 16):

### **Add PATH in Git Bash Permanently | Windows Only**

Just in case you are still wondering how to **add a path permanently in git bash** here is the *step-by-step* process **for Windows users**:

1. Create `.bashrc` in user's root folder using the below command. It will open notepad and ask you to create the file, click **yes**.

   ```
   notepad ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Put the directory you want to add as below, for more than 1 items repeat the same format in next line:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:"/c/folder/folder/"
   ```
3. Save the file and relaunch the bash.
4. Next launch will give you a warning like `WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.` but git bash will handle it by creating the required files.

---

### **SOME INSIGHTS**

1. Git Bash doesn't fetch Window's environment PATH, it maintains its PATH separately in more like a Linux way.
2. You can run `export PATH=$PATH:"/c/folder/folder/"` in cmd to add a directory to path, but it will be only for the current session once you close the bash, it will be gone.
3. `.bashrc` is a shell script file that will be executed every time you launch a new git bash window. So you can add any type of bash command here. We simply added the `export` command to add our desired directory to PATH.

Comment: The best answer so far

Comment: Definitely the best answer for Windows users. It also works seamlessly with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Just to note: If .profile already exists, you will need to add the export code to the .profile file too.

Answer (score 2):

According to this SO post, you need to escape Program Files with quotes. [git-bash $PATH cannot parse windows directory with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557224/git-bash-path-cannot-parse-windows-directory-with-space)

Comment: FWIW, in your first post, you have a single quote *before* the : which won't work. I'd debug by trying to set your path to just the maven bin directory to avoid parse errors in other parts of your path.

Comment: Also, to debug, you don't need to edit .bashrc, you can change for your current session at the prompt. Also 'source ~/.bashrc' will rerun the script.

Comment: Thx, that are very good hints. But unfortunately it is not working, no matter how I change it.