# When I run the git-gui in git bash on windows 10 I get "line 3: exec: wish: not found"

Tags: windows, git

I've been using git and the git gui command on windows for about 2 years with no issues.  Recently, I installed ubuntu on windows 10 and enabled the windows subsystem for linx (wsl) and installed git in the ubuntu bash, thinking I'd run git command from there.  Ever since, git is quite broken when I use the git bash as part of git for windows.

When I run git gui in the git bash prompt in git for windows I get

```
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-gui: line 3: exec: wish: not found
```

One thing I find really mystifying about the above output is that the slash before git-gui is a '\' backslash while the others are forward slashes, though it's probably irrelevent?

I can still successfully run git gui from the windows context menu (when I right click a folder).

Things I've tried:

- uninstalled git from ubuntu
- uninstalled ubuntu
- uninstalled git for windows and reinstalled after restart
- uninstalled git for windows, removed git folder from program files, and reinstalled after restart
- installed wish by installing tk on windows https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin
- reinstalled git to C drive (avoiding the space in "program files" which can cause bugs).
- Added c:\Git\mingw64\bin to my user path variable

activeTCl/bin (which contains the wish.exe) is on my system path.  When I run 'wish --version' in git bash a little empty window pops up, wish seems accessible, whatever it is.  Never needed wish or ActiveTcl to run git commands before, so I'm a bit mystified by that as well!  Anyhelp would be appreciated!  If wish is needed by git for windows why isn't it installed by the git for windows installer?

As requested, Here's the options I used when installing git for windows:

- Installed to C:/Git
- Components: ✔️ git Bash Here, ✔️ git Gui Here, ✔️ Associate .git* configuration files with the default text editor, ✔️ Associate .sh files to be run with Bash.
- Use Visual Studio Code as Git's Default editor.
- Path: How would you like to use Git form the command line?  Git from the command line and also from 3rd-party software.
- https transport backend: use the openSSL library
- line endings: checkout windows-style, commit unix-style
- terminal emulator: use MinTTY
- extra options:  ✔️ enable file system caching, ✔️ enable git credential manager, ✔️ enable symbolic links
- did not opt for experimental built-in add -i/-p

Comment: Have a look at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78595

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the suggestion, but that forum addresses a similar issue but for gitk on linux.  I'm on windows and I have installed wish.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. `git gui` works from git bash in my case. I can't read that but looks similar: https://blog.zdenekvecera.cz/item/3669-git-for-windows-chyba-line-3-exec-wish-not-found/

Comment: You can fin the relevant code [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/windows/git-gui.sh), but in my case in windows cmd: `>where git C:\Git\cmd\git.exe` but `>where wish INFORMATION: Es konnten keine Dateien mit dem angegebenen Muster gefunden werden.` You are working on windows? Perhaps include all steps from installation...

Comment: @Christoph I can't reproduce on my other machine either.  :)  Thanks for the link I added "C:\Git\bin" and "C:\Git\mingw64\bin" to my path.  No dice :(

Comment: @Christoph both `where git` and `where wish` return mulitple file path results for me.  I wonder if that could be a problem...

Comment: @RobinNelson, Can you post the output of ```which -a git-gui``` and ```echo $PATH``` from git-bash and output of ```echo %PATH%``` from Windows cmd ? ( You can redact paths which you would not like to show)

Comment: @RobinNelson, Have you tried running ```git-gui``` and ```git gui``` in git-bash ? Both the commands give the same error ?

Comment: Does the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: You need to put your comment below the answer!

Comment: tldr; is try `git-gui` instead of `git gui` and live the rest of your life in peace, never knowing why `git gui` broke in git bash ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a fresh installation of git with version `2.24.0.windows.2` with similar options as mentioned in the question.

I ran the `which` command on git-bash to get the path from where git-gui is being executed.

```
$ which -a git-gui
/cmd/git-gui
```

Check if `/cmd` is there in your `PATH` using `echo $PATH` in git bash or check if `C:/Git/cmd` is there in your `PATH` using `echo %PATH%` in Windows cmd. If not, then you can add it to your `PATH` variable (either Windows cmd or git-bash).

If the `which` command yields multiple paths, check if `/cmd/git-gui` executes well from git bash and remove the other paths(*caution!* refers to multiple paths found for `git-gui`) from the `PATH` variable.

I get the same error though when I assume that `/cmd` is not in my path

```
# Simulate an empty PATH variable
$ export PATH=:

# Run git-gui from git-core directory
$ C:/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui
C:/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui: line 3: exec: wish: not found
```

Another case where multiple paths exist for git-gui :

```
# Simulate PATH variable with the following directories
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/mingw64/libexec/git-core/:/cmd

# Run git-gui
$ git-gui
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui: line 3: exec: wish: not found

# Lists the paths 
$ which -a git-gui
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui
/cmd/git-gui
```

**Note**: 
`which` command can be used to `Write the full path of COMMAND(s) to standard output.` and the argument
`-a` is used to `Print all matches in PATH, not just the first`

---

I found a closed [issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/448) on git for Windows GitHub repository. Seems unrelated at first sight, however on seeing the commit message of the [fix](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/51afad7c6caf3fd03505769a85ac7a2bf199c669) it provides some background on why you might be facing the error.

> git-gui (Windows): use git-gui.exe in `Create Desktop Shortcut`
>
> When calling `Repository>Create Desktop Shortcut`, **Git GUI assumes
>   that it is okay to call `wish.exe` directly on Windows. However, in
>   Git for Windows 2.x' context, that leaves several crucial environment
>   variables uninitialized,** resulting in a shortcut that does not work.
>
> **To fix those environment variable woes, Git for Windows comes with a
>   convenient `git-gui.exe`, so let's just use it when it is available.**
>
> This fixes #448
>
> Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin

As highlighted in the commit message above, the author clearly points out to use `git-gui.exe` located in the `/cmd` directory.

---

As a final note, I would suggest OP to :

- Check `PATH` variable of Windows cmd and git-bash for conflicting directories containing `git-gui` using `where` and `which` commands respectively (*Windows cmd `PATH` env is passed on to git-bash*)
- Simulate an empty `PATH` variable as I have shown above and add only `/cmd` to the `PATH` variable of git-bash and then check if you are able to run `git-gui` from git-bash
- Confirm if `git-gui` runs in Windows cmd
- Check if you are adding the directory to the env variable `PATH` correctly
  (*Windows [cmd](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) and git [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45980107/10155936)*)
- Try running `git-gui` and `git gui`, do both the commands in git-bash give the same error ?

---

> I've been using git and the git gui command on windows for about 2
>   years with no issues. Recently, I installed ubuntu on windows 10 and
>   enabled the windows subsystem for linx (wsl) and installed git in the
>   ubuntu bash, thinking I'd run git command from there. Ever since, git
>   is quite broken when I use the git bash as part of git for windows.

To reproduce this, I

1. Setup a Windows 10 VM (Build 1909, Single Language Home Edition)
2. Install git for windows version `2.24.0.windows.2`

   - Git installation location : `C:\Git`

     - Similar options as you mention in the question except for the editor
       **Observations**

       - `C:\Git\cmd` is added to the `PATH` environment variable of Windows cmd (and therefore git-bash too)
   - Both the commands `git-gui` and `git gui` work from git-bash
3. Turn on Windows feature `Windows Subsystem for linux` for `Bash on Ubuntu Windows`
4. Install Ubuntu app from Microsoft store (Ubuntu 18.04)(git was pre-installed)
5. Update git to the latest version using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-i-update-to-a-newer-version-of-git-using-apt-get)
6. git works both for bash and windows running at `2.24.0` and `2.24.0.windows.2` respectively
7. Both the commands `git gui` and `git-gui` work as expected from git-bash
8. Uninstalled ubuntu for bash and turned off wsl, and it still works

---

Further [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/10155936) can be done using git's environment [variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging).

> `GIT_EXEC_PATH` determines where Git looks for its sub-programs (like
>   git-commit, git-diff, and others). You can check the current setting
>   by running git --exec-path.

- Run this command `git --exec-path` on git-bash, and verify if it
  shows : `C:/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`

> `GIT_TRACE` controls general traces, which don’t fit into any
>   specific category. This includes the expansion of aliases, and
>   delegation to other sub-programs.

- Run this command `GIT_TRACE=1 git gui`, and show the output
  (which includes the resolved exec directory for `git-gui`)

> GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM, if set, disables the use of the system-wide
>   configuration file. This is useful if your system config is
>   interfering with your commands, but you don’t have access to change or
>   remove it.

- Try running this command `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=1 git gui`

---

You can open a new issue [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues), if nothing else works.

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer and attempt to reproduce the problem.  
The results from the commands you suggested were mostly not noteworthy, execpt:
`$ GIT_TRACE=1 git gui
13:55:37.606832 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Git/mingw64/bin
13:55:37.608861 git.c:702               trace: exec: git-gui
13:55:37.608861 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-gui
C:/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-gui: line 3: exec: wish: not found`

Comment: I'm not sure if I could do this before, but I can run both `git-gui` and `git gui` from cmd.  Also, I can run `git-gui` from git bash, but still can't run `git-gui` from bash.  So, I'm just going to call it good there and just run the command with the hyphen.  I don't know if anything you suggested actually allowed me to run `git-gui` but your answer was thorough and explicative, so you get a nice green check.

Comment: Also, I removed `/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui` from my path, leaving `c:/git/cmd` on the path.  That might have been part of the fix that allowed `git-gui` to run from git bash.

Answer (score 0):

So this is too long for a comment: Have a look [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec+magic):

> So why doesn't the following attempt work?
>
> ```
>     exec wish "$0" "$@"
> ```
>
> The reason is that some versions of sh have a bug. If there are no
>   arguments, these broken sh's will still expand "$@" into a single
>   empty argument. Oops.
>
> The sh syntax ${VAR+VALUE} expands to VALUE if $VAR is set, and
>   nothing otherwise. We abuse this syntax to work around the buggy sh
>   implementations. Recall that the first argument is named $1. If it
>   exists, then we use "$@"; otherwise we do nothing:
>
> ```
>     exec wish "$0" ${1+"$@"}
> ```

I assume you are on Windows:

Go to `...\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`. Then you should find `git-gui`. If you open it with an editor, it looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tcl ignores the next line -*- tcl -*- \
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"
...
```

in my case.

**I am not an expert here and I don't unerstand the details in the link above**, but as it is only a skript and you already re-installed everything, I would give it a try

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tcl ignores the next line -*- tcl -*- \
exec wish "$0" ${1+"$@"}
...
```

I hope that helps and that it doesn't destroy anything ;-)

Comment: nice try!  I commented out `exec wish "$0" -- "$@"` and added what you suggested.  Same error.  `C:/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-gui: line 4: exec: wish: not found`

Comment: Yes, it's still a problem.  That would be great!

Comment: Please discribe once in detail, which options you choose when installing Git and please show `git version`. If I don't see anything then, I'll start a bounty.

Comment: I added the details at the end of my original question @Christoph

Comment: git version 2.24.0.windows.2