# Adding my Google Drive git as git remote no such directory

Tags: git, google-drive-api

I have followed answer: [Can I push/pull directly from my google drive online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947502/can-i-push-pull-directly-from-my-google-drive-online)
but still cannot get this to work.

My situation:
I have Google Drive .git directory 'Street Search Latest' synced with my laptop at home (not using git, just using Drive sync functionality).

Now I created .git local directory on desktop computer, and I want to fetch/pull the files from 'Street Search Latest' onto my desktop computer. Note with Google Drive, you can only sync files to one computer, so 'Street Search Latest' cannot be synced to my desktop computer.

In Git Bash on my desktop, I can `cd /c/Documents and Settings/will__000/Google Drive` and I am in the local Google Drive folder on my desktop, which by the way has some *different* files synced from *same* Google account.

As above answer, it advises to access a Google Drive git directory, or to add the directory as remote repository, I should use syntax like:

```
'/c/Documents and Settings/will__000/Google\ Drive'
```

'No such file or directory' doesn't work, no surprise to me since directory on my local drive is 'Google Drive' not 'Google'.

```
'/c/Documents and Settings/will__000/Google Drive\ Drive'
```

no such file or directory

```
'/c/Documents and Settings/will__000/Google\'
```

no such file or directory

The solution above adamant that \ then space in the middle is the syntax to use, do I need to somehow create SSH key in Google Drive git directory? How would I do this?

Also, my Google Drive folder with Google drive icon on desktop computer is clearly visible, but now I have just re-installed Google Backup and Sync, and I am not clear if it is properly syncing just the existing Desktop Google Drive folder to Google Drive, it shows as unticked box next to the name, and if I try to tick the box, it says it is sub-folder or parent folder of a folder that's already been added.

Perhaps Backup and Sync isn't automatically picking up the existing sync setting of the Google Drive files on my desktop computer with Google Drive in the cloud, not sure if this is connected.

To test this further, I created new folder and file in my desktop Google Drive folder, specified this file to backup and sync, which it said it was then syncing. Then in Google Drive online I can see this file as 'edited' but doesn't appear in the online folder list yet, even after logging in and out of Google Drive online once.

Tx kindly any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is with the space in the path name. It looks like you are adding an escape (backslash '\') before the space in 'Google Drive', what about the spaces in 'Documents and Settings'?

A quick search online suggests you might be able to use double quotes for windows paths with spaces instead of the backslash.

For example `C:/Users/"My Folder"`, from: [git-bash $PATH cannot parse windows directory with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557224/git-bash-path-cannot-parse-windows-directory-with-space)

So in your case you could also try using `/c/"Documents and Settings"/will__000/"Google Drive"`

Comment: Thanks @Scott, actually though I forgot to put quotes around _whole_ path in the question, just edited, your escape comment correct I think. I still have problem though `git remote add street /c/'Documents and Settings'/will__000/Google\ Drive\'Croydon CON29 Search'\'Street Search Latest'` in Git SCM on Windows just changes the prompt from $ to >, but doesn't add remote repo. This folder on Google Drive does have .git file. Also tried `git remote add street /c/'Documents and Settings'/will__000/'Google Drive'\ Drive\'Croydon CON29 Search'\'Street Search Latest'` no dice.

Comment: Sorry @Scott put your answer as top, actually you did solve this problem of no such directory as I asked it, now I need to ask separate question as to why this is still not creating the repo.