# Unable add Google Drive .git directory as remote repo, Git SCM > prompt confusion

Tags: git, google-drive-api

FYI the question originally identified as possible duplicate is mine, I still have outstanding issue as identified in this follow-on question. I have followed answer: [Can I push/pull directly from my google drive online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947502/can-i-push-pull-directly-from-my-google-drive-online) but still not working for me. Not clear if I'm doing something wrong in Git, Google Drive settings, Google Backup and Sync, or combination.

Maybe I can access the Google Drive directory in Git SCM, though not sure actually see below, but anyway cannot add the .git directory there as a remote repo.

My situation: I have Google Drive .git directory 'Street Search Latest' synced with my laptop at home (not using git, just using Drive sync functionality).

Now I created .git local directory on desktop computer, and I want to fetch/pull the files from 'Street Search Latest' onto my desktop computer. Note with Google Drive, you can only sync files to one computer, so 'Street Search Latest' cannot be synced to my desktop computer.

In Git Bash on my desktop, I am trying commands as code below.

You will see I have a bad habit of putting spaces in file directory names, but seem to have got round this, and with another SO fellow's answer have got past 'no such directory' errors. But I don't know why or what the `>` prompt is:

```
will__000@Will1 MINGW64 /c/Documents and Settings/will__000/Google Drive
$ cd 'C:\Users\will__000\PycharmProjects\Street Search Git'

will__000@Will1 MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/Street Search Git (master)
$ git remote add origin /c/'Documents and Settings'/will__000/'Google Drive'\ Drive\'Croydon CON29 Search'\'Street Search Latest'
> ^C

will__000@Will1 MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/Street Search Git (master)
$ git remote add origin /c/'Documents and Settings'/will__000/Google\ Drive\'Croydon CON29 Search'\'Street Search Latest'  
>
```

I can only control-C to break out from the `>` prompt, which seems to be ?running a different application? within SCM, where any commands I type at the `>` prompt seem to do nothing (tried "ls", "*help", "git status", "1" etc...).

The solution above adamant that \ then space in the middle is the syntax to use, do I need to somehow create SSH key in Google Drive git directory? How would I do this?

Also, my Google Drive folder with Google drive icon on desktop computer is clearly visible, but now I have just re-installed Google Backup and Sync, and I am not clear if it is properly syncing just the existing Desktop Google Drive folder to Google Drive, in settings it shows as unticked box next to the name, and if I try to tick the box, it says it is sub-folder or parent folder of a folder that's already been added.

Perhaps Backup and Sync isn't picking up the existing sync setting of the Google Drive files on my desktop computer with Google Drive in the cloud, not sure if this is connected.

To test this further, I created new folder and file in my desktop Google Drive folder, specified this file to backup and sync, which it said it was then syncing and shows in desktop Google Drive with green tick as synced. Yet even after logging in and out of Google Drive online twice, and after several hours still doesn't appear in cloud Google Drive.

Tx kindly any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding my Google Drive git as git remote no such directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899819/adding-my-google-drive-git-as-git-remote-no-such-directory)

Comment: I really, really recommend you don't do this. If you want 2 "synced" git repos, with a cloud backup, a free gitlab.com account is a much safer option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @pinoyyid I didn't know that, will try that and transfer when time, I can wing it for now just downloading and uploading code when using desktop, as it's just me working on this. I'd give you +1 if I could. Assume Gitlab is completely unrelated to Github or Bitbucket? Also intrigued to know what security issues are with Google Drive, obviously wouldn't use it for real commercial project, but still interested to know exactly.

Comment: the issue isn't security. it's the ability for the two sync methods to corrupt data. Somewhere in the blog sphere is a long and detailed article why you shouldn't do it. From memory, that was using dropbox, but the principle is the same.