# Finding the PATH which my Git Bash executes

Tags: bash, git, path, gdb

I'm trying to install a GDB debugger onto my Git Bash for Windows 10, but after downloading the gdb-8.2.tar.gz file and extracting it into a folder gdb-8.2, I've been unable to locate the path for which git bash could locate this program, thus it reports "bash: cdgb command not found".

I assume I'm putting the folder in the wrong directory. Question: What command can I use to find out what path git bash is currently using to execute so that I can place my folder gdb-8.2 there?

I'm well aware of what directory my git is located in. I'm asking where can I place this and future files for git bash to locate and execute.

Comment: What `gdb-8.2.tar.gz` did you download? Does it contain just the sources for GDB?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand all of this, but wouldn't you need to install the debugger using a package manager for whatever linux distro is being emulated thought windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bash: cdgb command not found

This should be a `$PATH` issue: check the output of `echo $PATH` (from your `git bash` session), and make sure it references a folder which includes the executable `cdgb`.

If not, type (still in that same git bash session, for testing)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/including/cdgb
```

That would be:

```
export PATH=/c/path/to/folder
```

If you have spaces in that path, see "[`git-bash $PATH` cannot parse windows directory with space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24557224/6309)".

Comment: This is what i was looking for but when I use the export PATH, do I include the c drive? Can you type a sample path